# Trying to parse a json file, function fails to return results

Tags: android, json

I have a working android application which lists books. The books in my application are statically added one by one by creating a Book object for each book. I want to change the way my application takes in the books such that instead of creating a book object for each book, I would read the needed information from a json file. I have created a function to parse the json file and called in in the same method where I initialize my book objects. I want to replace the chunk of code where I add each book through a new book object with the parseJson function. This leads me to the following problem:

If I remove the chunk of code where I add the books manually and replace it with the parseJson function, no books appear on the screen.

If I call the parseJson function, without removing the chunk of code where books are added manualy, the function works and I have duplicates of each book appearing on the screen.

The problem is essentially boiled down to this: The parseJson function does not work if the chunk of code where I initalize the book objects is removed.

this is the function where I read the json file:

```
 private void parseJson() {
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, "https://api.myjson.com/bins/15iviz", null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d("RESPONSE", response.toString());
                    try {
                        JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("results");
                        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                            jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                            String imageUrl = jsonObject.getString("url");
                            String title = jsonObject.getString("title");
                            String author = jsonObject.getString("author");
                            double price = jsonObject.getDouble("price");
                            int downloads = jsonObject.getInt("downloads");
                            int rating = jsonObject.getInt("rating");

                            Books.add( new Book(imageUrl, title, author, price, downloads, rating));

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO: Handle error
                }
            });


    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

this is the function in which I declared my book instances:

```
private void initImageBitmaps() {

    Log.i("HomeActivity", "initImageBitmaps()");


    Book book1 = new Book("https://imgur.com/5qLyBTr.jpg", "Doktor Ofboli", "Vasko Vasilev", 100.0, 321, 2);
    Book book2 = new Book("https://imgur.com/5qLyBTr.jpg", "Zoki Poki", "Vasko Vasilev", 70.0, 231, 3);
    Book book3 = new Book("https://imgur.com/5qLyBTr.jpg", "Sekerna Prikazna", "Vasko Vasilev", 30.0, 12, 1);
    Book book4 = new Book("https://imgur.com/5qLyBTr.jpg", "Pekolot", "Ivan Ivanov", 90.0, 666, 3);
    Book book5 = new Book("https://imgur.com/5qLyBTr.jpg", "Raj", "Ivan Ivanov", 0.0, 420, 4);
    Book book6 = new Book("https://imgur.com/5qLyBTr.jpg", "Kamasutra", "Ivan Ivanov", 0.0, 69, 5);
    Book book7 = new Book("https://imgur.com/5qLyBTr.jpg", "Cistsiliste", "Kiril Kirov", 50.0, 100, 3);

    Books.add(book1);
    Books.add(book2);
    Books.add(book3);
    Books.add(book4);
    Books.add(book5);
    Books.add(book6);
    Books.add(book7);

    parseJson();

    Log.e ("BOOKS", Books.toString());
   // parseExampleJson();

    initVereticalRecyclerView(Books);
    initFirstHorizontalRecyclerView(Books);
    initSecondHorizontalRecyclerView(Books);
}
```

If these book instances are removed the parser will not parse any books, if they stay the paresr will work resulting in two instances of every book, how can I solve this?

Here is the json I am parsing: http://myjson.com/15iviz

requested chunk of code:

```
private void initVereticalRecyclerView(ArrayList<Book> books) {

    Log.i("HomeActivity", "initRecyclerView()");

    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.home_recycler_view3);
    HomeActivityViewAdapter adapter = new HomeActivityViewAdapter(this, books);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
}
```

HomeActivity.java: this is where all of the realated code is: https://codeshare.io/5PlwDw (currently taking books from the declared book objects and and example array)

If needed I will upload my entire project on github and link it here.

Comment: Use Gson for creating your Booking Object rather than manually parse one by one. It is far more effective and  fast than manual

Comment: Can you show the `initVereticalRecyclerView()` method?

Comment: what does it mean

Comment: i think the problem was parsing a JSON

Comment: I cant understand the question and error

Comment: what is the main issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by calling methods which initialize the recyclerviews immediately after the for loop. Codes looks like this now:

```
private void parseJson() {
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
        (Request.Method.GET, "https://api.myjson.com/bins/15iviz", null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d("RESPONSE", response.toString());
                try {
                    JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("results");
                    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                        jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        String imageUrl = jsonObject.getString("url");
                        String title = jsonObject.getString("title");
                        String author = jsonObject.getString("author");
                        double price = jsonObject.getDouble("price");
                        int downloads = jsonObject.getInt("downloads");
                        int rating = jsonObject.getInt("rating");

                        Books.add( new Book(imageUrl, title, author, price, downloads, rating));

                    }

                    initVereticleRecyclerView(Books);
                    initFirstHorizontalRecyclerView(Books);
                    initSecondHorizontalRecyclerView(Books);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            }
        });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Add a dependency `implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'` in your gradle file first

Create your classes like this

```
    import java.util.List;

    public class BooksResponse {
    private ArrayList<Book> results;

    public void setResults(ArrayList<Book> results){
        this.results = results;
    }

    public ArrayList<Book> getResults(){
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return 
            "Bookings{" + 
            "results = '" + results + '\'' + 
            "}";
        }
}
```

and

```
public class Book {
    private int downloads;
    private String author;
    private double price;
    private int rating;
    private String title;
    private String url;

    public void setDownloads(int downloads){
        this.downloads = downloads;
    }

    public int getDownloads(){
        return downloads;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author){
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getAuthor(){
        return author;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price){
        this.price = price;
    }

    public double getPrice(){
        return price;
    }

    public void setRating(int rating){
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public int getRating(){
        return rating;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title){
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url){
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getUrl(){
        return url;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return 
            "ResultsItem{" + 
            "downloads = '" + downloads + '\'' + 
            ",author = '" + author + '\'' + 
            ",price = '" + price + '\'' + 
            ",rating = '" + rating + '\'' + 
            ",title = '" + title + '\'' + 
            ",url = '" + url + '\'' + 
            "}";
        }
}
```

Add create a method like this

```
private ArrayList<Book> getBooks(String json){
        Gson gson=new Gson();
        BooksResponse books=gson.fromJson(json, BooksResponse.class);
        return books.getResults();
    }
```

Now pass your json response to the method above and get the list of books

```
private void parseJson() {
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, "https://api.myjson.com/bins/15iviz", null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d("RESPONSE", response.toString());
                    ArrayList<Book> books=getBooks(response.toString());
                    if(books!=null && books.size>0){
                     initVereticalRecyclerView(books);
                     initFirstHorizontalRecyclerView(books);
                     initSecondHorizontalRecyclerView(books);
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO: Handle error
                }
            });


    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first call API, and handle it according to the response :

first call parseJson() from where you are calling initImageBitmaps().
and after you get the reponse (whether it is error or success) handle it by calling initImageBitmaps().

Update code as follows, call parseJson() from where initImageBitmaps() was being called.

```
    private void parseJson() {
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                (Request.Method.GET, "https://api.myjson.com/bins/15iviz", null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d("RESPONSE", response.toString());
                        if(Books == null){
                            Books = new ArrayList<Book>();
                        }
                        try {
                            JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray("results");
                            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                                jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
                                String imageUrl = jsonObject.getString("url");
                                String title = jsonObject.getString("title");
                                String author = jsonObject.getString("author");
                                double price = jsonObject.getDouble("price");
                                int downloads = jsonObject.getInt("downloads");
                                int rating = jsonObject.getInt("rating");



                                Books.add( new Book(imageUrl, title, author, price, downloads, rating));
                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        //HANDLE RESPONCE
                        initImageBitmaps();

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // TODO: Handle error

                        Toast.makeText(context, "No respose", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });


        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }





    private void initImageBitmaps() {

        Log.i("HomeActivity", "initImageBitmaps()");

//
//        Book book1 = new Book("https://imgur.com/5qLyBTr.jpg", "Doktor Ofboli", "Vasko Vasilev", 100.0, 321, 2);
//        Book book2 = new Book("https://imgur.com/5qLyBTr.jpg", "Zoki Poki", "Vasko Vasilev", 70.0, 231, 3);
//        Book book3 = new Book("https://imgur.com/5qLyBTr.jpg", "Sekerna Prikazna", "Vasko Vasilev", 30.0, 12, 1);
//        Book book4 = new Book("https://imgur.com/5qLyBTr.jpg", "Pekolot", "Ivan Ivanov", 90.0, 666, 3);
//        Book book5 = new Book("https://imgur.com/5qLyBTr.jpg", "Raj", "Ivan Ivanov", 0.0, 420, 4);
//        Book book6 = new Book("https://imgur.com/5qLyBTr.jpg", "Kamasutra", "Ivan Ivanov", 0.0, 69, 5);
//        Book book7 = new Book("https://imgur.com/5qLyBTr.jpg", "Cistsiliste", "Kiril Kirov", 50.0, 100, 3);
//
//        Books.add(book1);
//        Books.add(book2);
//        Books.add(book3);
//        Books.add(book4);
//        Books.add(book5);
//        Books.add(book6);
//        Books.add(book7);
//
//        parseJson();

        Log.e ("BOOKS", Books.toString());
        // parseExampleJson();

        initVereticalRecyclerView(Books);
        initFirstHorizontalRecyclerView(Books);
        initSecondHorizontalRecyclerView(Books);
    }
```

Reason : This is happening because parseJson is calling volley asynchronously, and its data is not being handled after getting data from parseJson. The static code you have written is working because you call initImageBitmaps() after adding books in array, and this is not happening after getting response from Volley.

Comment: I called parseJson() before calling initImageBitmaps() but the result is the same.

Comment: dont call initImageBitmaps() right after parseJson(), use my code and just call parseJson()

Comment: from where you are calling initImageBitmaps()?

Comment: from onCreate()

Comment: calling initImageBitmaps() from parseJson() does not work as well.

Comment: issue is pretty clear, you need to add it to recyclerview when you get it from server. In original code you are not doing it.

Comment: If you mean that I should add the three methods which initialize the 3 recyclerviews in the body of parseJson(), I have already tried that and it does not work.